# AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:

Tags: java, android, gradle, process, exit

I have this problem in my first java application in android studio 2021.2.1  : when I click Run i get this error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D76f2.png)

I tried to upgrade Gradle version and I used this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin to make sure that the plugin and the gradle versions are suitable but still doesent work . I changed JAVA_HOME variable to: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre and none of these solutions is working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I disabeled my anti virus Smadav and it worked ; it seems that smadav was blocking the process